# Display the content of a list on a dynamically changing gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview

I have (asp) GridView with an item template inside. There are ten item templates with one textbox each. The GridView is bound in the behind code. A data table is made and depending on certain criteria only certain columns will be visible. This is how the table changes dynamically based on user criteria.

This is the code I use to collect the values inside those textboxes.

```
            List<string> myList = new List<string>();

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (GridView1.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                    {
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl($"TB{i}");

                        if (tb.Text == string.Empty)
                        {
                            myList.Add("Null Value");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string someVariableName = tb.Text;
                            myList.Add(tb.Text);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

The `TB{i}` references the text boxes in the item template. They are named TB0 - TB9. This code will take the values and combine them into the list. That list will be stored in the database.

The issue I'm facing is redistributing those values back to the text boxes after that string has been queried from the database. Essentially, the string is queried and stored in a variable. That variable is then split on a comma delimiter and stored inside a new list. Here is the code I have so far, `this is where the problem is.`

```
            TextBox dbInput = new TextBox();
            dbInput.Text = "box1,box2,box3,box4,box5,box6,box7,box8,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,box13,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,11,222,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,333,null,null,null,null,444,null,333,1343";

            List<string> stringList = dbInput.Text.Split(',').ToList();
            int counter = 1;

            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (GridView1.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                    {
                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl($"TB{i}");
                        tb.Text = stringList[i];
                    }
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }

            }
```

The input is hard coded in this instance (dbInput). I'm fairly certain the issue is this line `tb.Text = stringList[i];`. The reason for that is because there should only be four columns displayed with this output. It only prints the first four entries of the list into the first four boxes on row one. Then it goes to row two and prints the same four entries, repeat.

I have tried changing `tb.Text = stringList[i];` `[i]` to another variable and incrementing it. I placed the variable outside the foreach loop but incremented it right after the inner for loop. This resulted everytime in this error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

Line 854.

```
Line 852:                    {
Line 853:                        TextBox tb = (TextBox)row.FindControl($"TB{i}");
Line 854:                        tb.Text = stringArray[counter];
Line 855:                    }
Line 856:                    counter = counter + 1;
```

How can I alter the code to loop through the contents of the list showing (for example) the first four items on row one, the next four items on row two and repeat till the list is empty?

Comment: Does the first part work (the values are collected and stored in the database) ?

Comment: Yes, that part works. I just didn't include the code for the database upload.

Comment: When you say "there should only be four columns displayed with this output" - is it displaying more ? Where is your logic for deciding which columns should be displayed, and is it executed before your grid population ?

Also would be good to see the markup if possible plz.